# Why submit() is not working on FireFox 23 on a file upload form?

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox

I have a file upload function on my website, it works correctly on Chrome, Safari, IE 7 & 10, but it just doesn't work with FireFox 23.0.1.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<iframe style="display:none" src="about:blank" id="up_frame" name="up_frame" onload="iFrameDone()"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Create(tag,type,obj){
    var n = document.createElement(tag);
    if(type) n.type = type;
    n.id = UniqueId();
    obj.appendChild(n);
    return n;
}
.
.
.
fm = Create("form",null,uplButton);
fl = Create("input","file",fm);
fl.name = "up_file";
if(ie){
   // Keep Internet Explorer from complaining
   // move the from to a proper place & apply some styles.
}else{
    fm.Opacity(0);  // make it transparent
}
fl.onchange = function(){
   fm.method = "post";
   fm.encoding = "multipart/form-data";
   fm.action = "upload";
   fm.target = "up_frame";
   fm.submit();
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is to create a form on the top of my Upload button, and then making it transparent, a trick to achieve visual uniformity in my design. When the user selects a file, the **onchange** event is triggered and the form submitted through a hidden **iframe**.

This works perfect on Chrome and Safari. In order to make it work on IE I had to keep the form visible because otherwise it complaints: "access denied", that's the why of the **if**, but as you can see, the form submission mechanism is the same for all browsers.

I traced the code with the FF debugger and at the point at which **submit** is about to be executed all the members of **fm** contain the expected values, but if I click on the **Single Step** button to execute **fm.submit()**, it seems to just skip the instruction without doing anything at all, nothing is sent to the server and no error/warning message is logged at the console, so I have no clue of what's going on.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT:**

In order to discard a similar problem like the one I had with IE, I tested with the form visible but still get the same behavior.

**ALSO NOTE THAT:**

This trick or a similar one is being used for all major email services, so there is a way to make it work, please don't give me answers like: "add a submit button".

This means no security problem, since I am not trying to force the upload of a specific file. What I'm trying to do is to pop up the "File upload" window and upload the file that the user chooses by his/her own free, aware and conscious will. But if the browsers does consider it a security issue then **why it is not logged in the console?** or otherwise reported to the user.

Comment: I suspect it's a security mechansim that disallows programatically submitting forms with file inputs, as the user might be tricked into uploading a file he doesn't want. It would need to be fired from a trusted user event, like a `click`. Try an extra submit button instead of the `onchange` event.

Comment: Bingo with the progammatic submission idea. That's exactly what it is. I've encountered it before myself. You should make that an answer @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, the Interent Explorer does complain about access denied when the form is in anyway outside the user's view by displaying the message "access denied" however when you make the form visible it does not complain and allows the upload to go on!!!.... (and @Adam) if do read carefully you would realize I already tried leaving the form visible, but that doesn't solve the problem!!!

Comment: @Adam: Yet I cannot find any reference for that behaviour. Also, a `FileReader` does allow getting files from the `onchange` event so it should not be an issue. Not going to answer before I find evidence :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after: uninstalling FF, downloading it from the official Mozilla web site and installing it again. For the record: if you plan to install Fire Fox, make sure you are downloading it from the official Mozilla web site...

This happened because I ignored a warning my antivirus gave me about the site from which I downloaded the first installation package.